# Looping and testing the result of a cte in a PostgreSQL trigger

Tags: postgresql, triggers, recursive-cte

PostgreSQL 11.1

I am using the following trigger to obtain a "new" chart number from the chart_gap table:

```
CREATE FUNCTION phoenix.next_chart()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF 
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
  -- Check for empty chart number
  IF NEW.chart_number is null or NEW.chart_number = 0 THEN
    WITH ins AS (
      SELECT chart_number
      FROM   chart_gap
      WHERE  pg_try_advisory_xact_lock(chart_number)
      LIMIT  1
    )
    DELETE FROM chart_gap c
    USING  ins i
    WHERE  i.chart_number = c.chart_number
    RETURNING i.chart_number INTO NEW.chart_number;
  END IF;

  RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$;
```

How would I add a test to be sure the chart_number that is returned does not already exist (in table patients) and if it does, then force a loop to get the next chart number in the table, etc.., until an unused chart_number is found? That is, the trigger must return new and *unused* chart_numbers.

TIA

Note: my initial thoughts are to use recursive cte, but think a straight forward loop might be faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect that you have a good reason for not using sequence values.

You could simply surround the code block with `LOOP` / `END LOOP;` and add a `SELECT count(*)` at the end to test if there are any rows with that `chart_number`. That should be safe from race conditions as long as every transaction takes that route.

You have to make sure that the `INSERT` takes place in the same transaction, while the advisory lock is held.

As an alternative to the advisory lock, you could also

```
SELECT chart_number
FROM chart_gap
FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
LIMIT 1;
```

which might be simpler.

Comment: Much thanks. The initial reason for not using a sequence, is that years ago (when this trigger was first written), I wanted to avoid using certain chart numbers. However, since the initial reason has long since been corrected, a sequence now would be good--but since chart numbers were initially somewhat randomly assigned, I still would have the problem of potentially producing a chart number that has already been used.

Comment: Set the sequence to a value higher than the vales in the table, then there won't be a collision.

Comment: You would think (hope) so, but values have been entered all over the map leaving 100's of thousand of skipped usable integers. :)  (Aside note, I just posted another related question -- I don't seem to be able to use the correct syntax for count(*). :(